# Unable to install Google API in Android

Tags: java, android

I want to create a map view application in android. If I click the Third Party Add-ons to install Google Api, I'm getting this error

> Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list.xml, reason:
>   File not found

Comment: why you are going for the third party? add google api. update your AVD also.

Comment: the problem is i want to install the google api...by clicking availabe packages-->third party,to install the google api.but if i m to click the third party i m getting the above error...is there any other way to install google api

Comment: download from available packages-->Android Repositories then choose google api level. Update your ADT  http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#downloading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit the URL to remove the "s" in `https` and try again. I've never seen it working with the downloads links provided in the Android developer docs.