# unable to install Google Play License Library" and "Google Play Downloader Library"

Tags: android

I have to install Google Play License Library" and "Google Play Downloader Library" packages i am following steps given at [Developer Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/expansion-files.html#Preparing)
 but i am not able to find above packages in sdk-manager.

screen-shot is available [here](http://www.dropbox.com/gallery/69822895/1/issues?h=284395)

i have tried the suggestions given in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8294061/unable-to-install-google-api-in-android).
advice me what to do?

Comment: I have update the link for screen shot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download a new version of the sdk manager, I had the same issue and with the lastest version the package appeared. http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

But that's not the hardest part to implement expansion file download ...
I have a lot of issue after importing the libraries...

Comment: BTW, your screenshot link don't work. It's refereeing to your personal dropbox account

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to download a new version of the sdk manager. Just run `<androidSdk>/tools/android --clear-cache`